# how to move different sub directories and files in to one directory in java

Tags: java, file, directory, nio

i have a requirement like to move all directories that have in multiple directories need to move into one directory

eg:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsQre.png)

i wanted to move all sub folders in to one folder called AU, US, UK like what ever i want...

expected out:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIdkY.png)

how to do these in java?

Comment: Use the Java NIO.2.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java NIO.2. Have a closer look for the usage. [Moving a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html)   You could only move single files or empty directory. Look at [Walking the File Tree](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html). Be aware this example is using relative paths from India directory.

```
Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("AU/floder"));

Files.move(Paths.get("US/Image2"),Paths.get("AU/floder/Image2"));
```